# Do they have scales?

Tags: species-identification, homework, ichthyology

Do *Channa striatus* and *Channa punctatus* have scales?

They are both snake headed species of the genus Channa. I'm trying to figure out the distinguishing characters.

Comment: Did you try to google the species names and the word "scale" and either look at pictures or one of the first links. Here is the search result I got with ["scale Channa-striata"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Channa-striata&oq=Channa-striata&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i60.2158j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=scale+Channa-striata) (the answer is in the second link).

Comment: I'm sorry. I shouldn't have created this post in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Channa striata

**Environment/climate/range**

> Freshwater; brackish; benthopelagic; pH range: 7.0 - 8.0; dH range: ? - 20; potamodromous (Ref. 51243); depth range 1 - 10 m (Ref. 2686), usually 1 - 2 m (Ref. 4515).   Tropical; 23°C - 27°C (Ref. 1672), preferred ?; 35°N - 18°S

**Length at first maturity / Size / Weight / Age**

> Maturity: Lm 18.0, range 23 - ? cm
>   Max length : 100.0 cm SL male/unsexed; (Ref. 2686); common length : 61.0 cm TL male/unsexed; (Ref. 44091); max. published weight: 3.0 kg (Ref. 40637)

Short description

> Dorsal spines (total): 0; Dorsal soft rays (total): 38-43; Anal spines: 0; Anal soft rays: 23 - 27. Body sub-cylindrical; head depressed; caudal fin rounded (Ref. 2847). The dorsal surface and sides is dark and mottled with a combination of black and ochre, and white on the belly; a large head reminiscent of a snake's head; deeply-gaping, fully toothed mouth; **very large scales** (Ref. 44091).

More information [here](http://www.fishbase.org/summary/Channa-striata.html)

---

### Channa punctata

**Environment / Climate / Range**

> Freshwater; brackish; benthopelagic; potamodromous (Ref. 51243).   Tropical; 22°C - 28°C (Ref. 2059), preferred ?

**Size / Weight / Age**

> Max length : 31.0 cm TL male/unsexed; (Ref. 4833); common length : 15.0 cm TL male/unsexed; (Ref. 6028)

**Description**

> In Sri Lanka, the young have a chocolate-coloured body with three yellow stripes which are lighter ventrally. There is also a golden lateral stripe from the snout, through the eye to the middle of the caudal fin. At 13 mm, black body **scales** appear along with three dark bands on the caudal fin. Adult colouration arrives at a size of 70 mm upwards ( Deraniyagala 1929 ).

More information [here](http://www.fishbase.org/summary/Channa-punctata.html) and [here](http://www.discoverlife.org/20/q?search=Channa%20punctata)